# How can i speed up my data write process in s3 using pySpark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have to write parquet files containing 700 000 rows each in s3 using PySpark. I am writing a data frame in a parquet file and saving it in the S3 using overwrite method.

For writing one data frame in one bucket, my code is taking 50 secs to complete, and I have to write around 6000 dataframes in the buckets. I want to optimize my code so that it should take max 30 sec.

This is the snippet of my code:

```
original_dataframe=spark.read.option('header', 'true').option('inferSchema','true').parquet("s3://"+bucketname+"/"+data_files_path)

distinct_df=original_df.distinct()
distinct_df_cache=distinct_df.cache() 
 

distinct_df_cache.coalesce(8).write.format("parquet")
.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true")
.mode("overwrite").save("s3://"+bucketname+"/"+data_files_path)
```

And I am using this spark submit command to run it.

```
sudo spark-submit --master yarn --executor-memory 48G --driver-memory 30g --num-executors 8 --executor-cores 8 --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=16 --conf spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema=true --conf spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown=true --conf spark.default.parallelism=90 --conf spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat=true my_Code.py
```

This whole process takes around 80 seconds on an average, from reading, till writing in the same bucket path.

What can I do to optimize it so that it should take around 30 seconds to complete the whole process for one loop. I have to run this code on loop 10 000 times in one go. Currently, it will take 80 X 10 000 = 800 000 secs. It will run for the whole day.

I want the results something like 40 X 10000 = 400 000 secs to complete whole process, if possible.

Comment: If you have more partitions to write and more executors then the writing operation will be executed in distributed manner.

Answer (score 1):

Usually increasing write parrallelism improves speed. Then increase both coalesce and shuffle parrallelism to 64 (you have 8 * 8 available writers from your spark submit configuration).

A downside is you will also increase number of produced s3 files but that should not be a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

1. option('inferSchema'. true) is really option("read through all the source data to work out what type each column is"). Recommend: unset
2. make sure you are using an s3 optimised committer which avoids renames. Consult the documentation of your Spark distribution.
3. python may be a good language for notebooks, but it can be less efficient in production. Consider either of:

- try and do it in an SQL statement
- write it in scala or java, get it on the classpath and have it invoked directly.

If you really want to maximise performance, start with spark-standalone and get that fast before worrying about distribution, as it is easier to benchmark and profile.